# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException . This is the error that is showing in my program pls help here is my code

Tags: java, android, xml, logcat

here is my mainActivity.java file i have created this project for making a TIC TAC TOE game but their is an error .

```
package com.example.tictactoe;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4,btn5,btn6,btn7,btn8,btn9,btnNewgame;
    int flag=0;
    int count=0;
    String b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();

    }
    private void init() {
        btnNewgame=findViewById(R.id.btnNewgame);
        btn1=findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2=findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3=findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4=findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5=findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6=findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7=findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8=findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9=findViewById(R.id.btn9);
    }
    public void check(View view) {
        Button btncurrent = (Button) view;
        count++;
        if(btncurrent.getText().toString().equals("")){
        if(flag==0){
            btncurrent.setText("X");
            flag=1;
        }
        else {
            btncurrent.setText("O");
            flag=0;
        }
        if(count>4){
            b1=btn1.getText().toString();
            b2=btn2.getText().toString();
            b3=btn3.getText().toString();
            b4=btn4.getText().toString();
            b5=btn5.getText().toString();
            b6=btn6.getText().toString();
            b7=btn7.getText().toString();
            b8=btn8.getText().toString();
            b9=btn9.getText().toString();
        }
        if(b1.equals(b2) && b2.equals(b3) && !b1.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b4.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b6) && !b4.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b5, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b7.equals(b8) && b8.equals(b9) && !b9.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b7, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b1.equals(b4) && b4.equals(b7) && !b1.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b2.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b8) && !b2.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b2, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b3.equals(b6) && b4.equals(b9) && !b9.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b1.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b9) && !b1.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }else if (b3.equals(b5) && b5.equals(b7) && !b3.equals(" ")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "The Winner is "+b3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        } else if (count==9) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Match Draw", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            newGame();
        }
        }
    }
    public void newGame(){
        finish();
    }
}
```

This my layout file ac

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TIC TAC TOE"

        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.455"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.288" />


    <GridLayout

        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:columnCount="3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"
             />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="133dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:onClick="check"/>

    </GridLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNewgame"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:onClick="newGame"
        android:text="@string/new_game"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Player2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Player 2 : O"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/player1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.644"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/player1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/player1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:text="Player 1 : X"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/gridLayout"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.06"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I cant find any problem my self but in the log cat it is showing that
here you can see at mainActivity.java line no 57 it is showing error but i dont know what is the error in my code

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tictactoe, PID: 11660
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:473)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
    at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
    at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
    at com.example.tictactoe.MainActivity.check(MainActivity.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1213)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
    at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 57, evaluating the equation `b1.equals(b2)` after clicking the first of the 9 buttons leads to a crash, since b1 and b2 still have the initial value `null` and do not yet contain a `string`. `b1.equals(...)` therefore leads to a `java.lang.NullPointerException` and to a program crash.